# How to change the default firebase storage bucket?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I have 2 storage buckets, one from Google cloud storage, and one created by firebase, the bucket created by firebase is the default, i want to change the default bucket and delete the bucket created by firebase.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do it from Firebase Console.
You will need to go to your Google Cloud Console and delete it from there.
 
1. Open the Cloud Storage browser in the Google Cloud Platform Console.
2. Select the checkbox of the bucket you want to delete.
3. Click Delete.
4. In the overlay window that appears, confirm you want to delete the bucket and its contents by clicking Delete.
Here is the explanation by GCP:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/deleting-buckets

Comment: Please include the relevant information in your answer.